# Display unique portal records based on a desired field in Filemaker 12

Tags: filemaker

I am completely new to Filemaker and I have a problem displaying distinct values on a portal according to a desired field.

This is a screenshot of the portal. It is displaying all Storage Type entries of a related building (BuildingID = 10): 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8. As you can see, the  Storage Type with ID 3 shows up more than once:

[image: Duplicate entries in portal]

And this is the underlying table:

[image: Duplicate values in table]

But I need something like a filter, so that in this portal the Storage Types are distinct or rather show up only once.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portals are not limited to displaying data 1 relationship away. Since the Storage Type is a foreign key for a 3rd table, you can set your portal to show that third table, as long as the three tables are connected in your relationship graph. You will still be able to display fields from the intermediary table, but the number of records will come from the 3rd table.